# How to decide on runtime whether to use ´for´ or ´parfor´ loop in matlab and why the differences between both of them are minor?

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing, lambda

I am trying to test the effect of `parfor` compared to `for` in matlab, I built simple [function calculates π](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/montecarlopimod.html) :

[image]

here is the function with the `parfor`:

```
function [calc_pi,epsilon] = calcPi(max)
format long;

in = 0;
tic
parfor k=1:max
    x = rand();
    y = rand();
    if sqrt(x^2 + y^2)<1
        in = in + 1;
    end
end

toc
calc_pi = 4*in/max; 
epsilon = abs(pi - calc_pi);
end
```

I run it with `parfor` and got this output:

```
>> [calc,err] = calcPi(1000000000)
Elapsed time is 92.2923 seconds.

calc =

   3.141638468000000


err =

     4.581441020690136e-05

>>
```

with the for loop I came with:

```
>> [calc,err] = calcPi(1000000000)
Elapsed time is 121.3432 seconds.

calc =

   3.141645132000000


err =

     5.247841020672439e-05
```

I have two questions:

1. Why both take about the same amount of time ? (Unlike showed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/using-parfor-to-run-loops-in-parallel-68756.html))
2. I would like to add an argument to the function indicates whether to
   use for or parfor with the minimal change in code:

   i.e. :

   ```
   if (use_par):
       parfor k=1:10
   else
      for k=1:10
   end

   <--rest of code here-->
   ```

   How can I write it with the minimal amount of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main requirement of `parfor` is that the loop executions are independant. Here they are clearly not as each iteration can update the variable `in`.

The good news is that you may be able to solve this by using `in(k)` instead.

---

One way to use one loop or the other without using extra code would be to put everything you do in a function or script, for example `doeverything.m`

then write

```
if (use_par):
    parfor k=1:10
       doeverything
    end
else
   for k=1:10
       doeverything
   end
end
```

Comment: It is not true at all using in(k) gives the same results!

Comment: @0x90 Too bad that I cannot try it myself. Could you check whether you set up `matlabpool` correctly and whether it helps if you dont assign to x and y but just use rand directly?